# connect .net applications on app server(window server 2008r2) with adfs using saml

Tags: .net, iis-7, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

We have adfs installed on separate server and want to connect .net applications located on app server(window server 2008 R2) using saml 2.0. What steps i need to authenticate all .net apps(deployed on IIS) with adfs installed on separate server.
I searched over google but didn't find any simple way to solve my issue.
Please support me... thanks in advance

Comment: After r&d, i configured .net apps deployed on IIS on test server(ws 2008r2). Steps used 1) Installed WIF on test server 2)Open WIF and provide web.config of the app, url of the app and metadata file of adfs server. 3)These steps automatically update the app config & create specific metadata for your app 4)Open App in VS & select project name in solution & open properties, and SSL Enable =True 5)App pool set LoadUserProfile=True. The above steps will configure .netapp 6)Now goto ADFS server, create relay party trust by providing specific metadata file created in step 3. follow next next...enjoy

Answer (score 0):

After r&d, i configured .net apps deployed on IIS on test server(ws 2008r2). Steps used 1) Installed WIF on test server 2)Open WIF and provide web.config of the app, url of the app and metadata file of adfs server. 3)These steps automatically update the app config & create specific metadata for your app 4)Open App in VS & select project name in solution & open properties, and SSL Enable =True 5)App pool set LoadUserProfile=True. The above steps will configure .netapp 6)Now goto ADFS server, create relay party trust by providing specific metadata file created in step 3. follow next next...enjoy